# Creating a wifi proxy from PC

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, proxy, modem

I am using PC which is connected to the internet through ethernet cable and modem. My friend uses the same modem, but he connect to it through wifi. However, I don't want to be responsible for illegal and copyrighted downloads, so I want to restrict websites such as ThePirateBay and PopcornTV from my wifi. Simply, I want to make a proxy such that when anyone try to access these websites through my wifi, a specified message will be displayed instead of website content.

Also, to prevent illegal uploads, I want to make something like approve test. When someone who uses my wifi upload a file or send something to server, I want to check SHA-256 of that file or message. If the hash is blacklisted, it should be rejected (or modified and then sent).

I am not sure how easy it would be to make what I want. I tried to google for some tutorials, but I didn't find anything like this. I don't ask if it is possible because I know it is. Modem is physical object, every message should go through modem, so there should be a way to proxy it.

It would be best if it is possible using just software approach (changing some parameters inside home gateway). If there is no builtin option for that, is there some modem simulator? Any other ideas would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

**The point of my question is NOT how to check if some message is blacklisted or how to modify its hash. These are just an EXAMPLES, so please avoid complaining that it is unreal to try to check file by hash. The main question is HOW TO INSPECT/MODIFY requests from users before sending data to server.**

Comment: Your blacklist idea is unrealistic.  There is no possible way to blacklist every file.  "Or send something to server" - What server?  Your idea can be broken by using a VPN, unless you want to block every single VPN service that exists (there are thousands of them) and (millions of BitTorrent websites) your website blacklist is a poor idea.  You can't force your friend to use your DNs configuration either.

Comment: "If the hash is blacklisted, it should be rejected (or modified and then sent)." this isn't possible.  I could get around your sha256 by modifying the file by a single bit with a hex editor on my PC which you have zero control over or simply using Winzip and adding a 1 byte text file

Comment: @Ramhound. It seems you missed the main point of my question. I only provided an example in what manner I would use the answer. What filters and what blacklisting system I would use is a side question (and also not for this topic). Please, read it carefuly before downvoting.

Comment: @Ramhound. What is wrong with my question? Is it out of scope? Is it too broad? I don't think so, because I carefuly readed the help center page about what and how to ask. What rule did I break? Should I ten times write that my question is not about checking hash, but about proxifying wifi.

Comment: @Ramhound. Again, after checking help center page, you can find [here](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) that according to all rules, my question is on-topic. I simply cannot figure out why downvote and what did I ask wrong. If you still think my question is off-topic, please provide a reason for it, or even beter help me approve the question, so it can possibly help someone in the future.

Comment: Voting is anonymous for this exact reason.  Explaining a downvote is something, the person who downvoted your question, is NOT required to do.  Giving me a hard time because I commented on your question and you happened to also be downvoted is the very definition of harassing me for simply saying something you don't agree with

Comment: "The main question is HOW TO INSPECT/MODIFY requests from users before sending data to server." Deep Packet Inspection (DPI) which can be easily defeated by using a VPN.  Your question is seeking possible solutions to a broad problem IMO, those type of questions, are best solve at a discussion forum IMO.  IMO you have not clearly defined the problem you want to solve so your question IMO is not clear.  Good Superuser questions are well defined and most of the time have clear defined solutions.

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting to do is not particularly practical, and parts may not be even theoretically practical, but I think you are asking the wrong question.

First problem you have is that the "modem" is not actually a modem, its a router with built in modem.   This means that when your friend is connected, the traffic is not traversing your PC.   In order to make it traverse your PC you will either need to modify the hardware setup to go through your PC and another Access Point or intercept the traffic on the router.  If you have a standard consumer-grade router this is almost impossible - unless you can run DD-Wrt, Tomato or similar, in which case its just very difficult.   You need to be aware that what you are talking about doing is also CPU intensive and your router may not be powerful enough.

Checking the SHA-256 of a file in transit, although possibly theoretically possible -  is not really practical - among other reasons, it will break streaming and tcp-connectivity.  Your device would have to recognise and download the whole file, then check it, before sending it on.  This will mean long delays, lots of resources used and will break the TCP stack because of timeouts etc.  Also, as commenters have suggested, it can easily be worked arround by using encryption, compression, character set representation shifting or a whole lot of other things.

To answer your edit - in order ot inspect/modify requests, you will need to install a proxy server on the router - one which is capable of inspecting and modifying data.

That said, might I suggest that your concept is flawed.   If you are trying to block The Pirate Bay and Popcorn TV, what you are probably wanting to do is block the bittorrent protocol - thats easy.  Simply limit incoming and outgoing traffic to known ports associated with acceptable services.  This will break the protocol, as it uses different ports to the kinds of things you can proxy.  Its also easy on the router as it does not require proxies etc.   [ Again, this may or may not be possible, depending on your router.  What router do you have ? ]

Comment: Most BT clients supports UPnP and randomized ports.  Like I said before, a VPN will get around blocking BT traffic, and you can configure VPN to run on any port also.

Comment: @Ramhound - I was proposing blocking all ports except for known useful ports - this would severely gimp Bittorrent.  If you are using a VPN, it would need to be over TCP - again, not ideal for bittorrent, but more importantly, no proxy solution would fix that either - but, depending on the OPs concerns, a VPN provider might nullify the risk of his ISP coming after him anyway.

Comment: @davidgo. Delayed requests and responses are not problem. Also, the technical details about how I will filter results and how I will prevent avoiding my proxy is something which is not related to this question. According to your answer, it is possible using specified router? Does it mean that I can find a ruter (or create myself one using, for example, Arduino) which will be able to tranfer all data from modem throught USB port to my PC, so I can inspect it, maybe modify, and then send back to modem?

Comment: I think you are underestimating the delays and damage it will cause to Internet connectivity.   You state that the technical details about how you will filter the results are not related to the question, but then ask if if its possible to do with a router - so you are, in effect, preventing a meaningful answer.    Transfering data from modem to USB port is doable with a appropriately crafted software - you might want to get a USB -> Ethernet dongle rather then deal with the added complexity of PPP - I'd imagine its possible to do this with Linux - but not easy...

Comment: You would need to  combine iptables, ebtables, bridges (and possibly vlans), as well as have appropriately tuned software on your PC.  You would be better off looking at some kind of IDS running on a decently specced router.